# wifi connection drops down [TP-LINK WN722N, Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Wi-Fi is no longer working after 30-40 mins in idle.
Terminal write this:

```
[1438.056750] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: fatal error
[1438.057339] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: HC died; cleaning up
[1438.064353] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[1438.064860] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel (2422 Mhz) reset status -22
[1438.065404] ath: phy0: Unable to set channel
[1438.266043] ath: phy0: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0x2069c87a
[1438.276892] ath: phy0: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[1438.377599] ath: phy0: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0x0
[1438.578444] ath: phy0: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0x485dc87a
[1438.589117] ath: phy0: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[1438.890195] ath: phy0: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0x485dc87a
```

Comment: Do you have another USB device that you can plug into that port as I wonder if there is something wrong with that port

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with plugging a good power to the port. On a desktop it was a dedicated hub with an external power supply unit, on Raspberry Pi 2 it was a 2.5A power supply. Also I've installed a new kernel from git - and it's(disconnection problem) gone! If you have any further troubles try to remove a case from USB stick and apply a good radiator and cooler to the chip - I did it from the start, but just cooling didn't saved my day